# Adding outlines to hair particles?

Tags: shaders

I'm trying to reach a flat cartoony look for my character but when I use any sort of option for cel shading it will never outline the hair particles, is it even possible? Could I somehow make a special shader to achieve that? The shadows are part of the texture.

[image: hair particles on animal model]

Comment: Blender's Freestyle doesn't work for you?

Comment: nope, it only outlines the base mesh

Comment: Sorry, worked in 2.79 for blender internal https://imgur.com/v2p44Ty ... what result do you expect ... do you have some reference? Get outline for every strand it became totally black or are you asking for silhouette of character including hairs? Anyway usually hairs for anime are done via polygons even they use curve thickness.

Comment: I was looking for a silhouette of the fur along with an outline of the model, for example if i draw over this image i'd want it to look like this, https://imgur.com/a/TfYDwOs  the second image is an example taken from Beastars, they don't use blender but they have particle fur and are using some sort of custom shader maybe? i was trying to emulate that effect

Answer (score 2):

*For silhouette outline is usually used Freestyle, but it is not working with Hairs. Since Freestyle is post process effect anyway, there is even probably faster to use Compositor to calculate this effect.*

---

You can try some node tree based on object separation - like *Index OB* or *Cryptomatte* and create outline with *Sobel*, *InPaint*, *Dilate-Erode* kind nodes.

### Option 01

For few objects you can arrange it with **Index OB** node and **Sobel** node to generate outline.

[image]
[image]

### Option 02

For more complex scene **Cryptomatte** works better, since you can generate outlines for all objects at once from **Pick** output directly. You don't need to select them one by one ... just reuse random colors of *Pick* output.

[image]
[image]

Note: Sometimes **Filter** node (like *Sobel*, *Perwitt*, ... type) generates from Cryptomatte's white color filled place, Increasing *Fac* over 1 fix that. I would say it is because *Cryptomatte's Pick* colors represents more dynamic range than *Filter* node can handle. Using this socket directly is not proper way of using it, it is more a hack so that is why I had to use *Math* (*Greater Than*) node because direct use handled white color in a wrong way again. *Greater Than* node clamps high values.

[image]