# Regular outline but for a transparent material

Tags: materials, shaders, transparency, outliner

I am trying to have my mesh with an Outline but at the same time being transparent inside.
The outline has to be only on the parts that would be viewable as if the mash was not transparent (I don't want to see the outline for the back part of the cube for instance).
Basically, I want the exact same outline but transparent materials inside. As you see, only the solidify is shown if I try just using a transparent shader.
Any ideas? Also, other methods are welcome (grease pencil collection outline, etc) At the moment I had no success.
[image: the outline needed]
[image: all black with material set to transparent]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the Freestyle feature? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/freestyle/introduction.html

Comment: What technique is used for your outline now? Have you tried this ...
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/303663/2214 or this
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/219100/2214

Comment: @Onyx I'm not familiar with the freestyle feature, I just know what it is used for usually I use the method I posted for outlines. I give it a try

Comment: @vklidu the one you suggested is the method I use already, but I need the mesh transparent while keeping the outline (and at the same time not having the outline for the part that wouldn't be visible if the mesh was not transparent). I know it sounds strange, but it is just a style I use on 2D work, that would like to recreate

Comment: So probably the second link is for you ... or if you are OK just to end up with only outline https://imgur.com/GMnZRMd you can try Holdout feature, but it takes transparent hole through whole scene https://imgur.com/nFTboWh

Comment: @vklidu   Very interesting method this one, I will give it a try. Thanks! For now I kind of manage with grease pencil outline and transparent shader for the mesh. I get the effect that I want. Problem is grease pencil outline makes render painfully slow with complex scene